# Faye unexpected error 200 tomcat

Tags: tomcat, websocket, faye

I use jRuby and I have the dev environment working fine on Puma server, and websockets work fine. On production, however, the application is deployed on Tomcat using warble. The websocket client gives

> Websocket connection to failed: Error during WebSocket handshake:
>   unexpected response code: 200

In the server log, I could see the onOpen Being triggered, but the websocket connection is lost.

Can you please help me?

Currently

Thanks,
Alex